# purchase of domain name and associate it to my computer

Tags: web, dns

my goal is to buy a domain name and associate it to my personal computer. I never did such a thing before. So I went to the following provider: https://www.lws.fr and during the process of buying a domain name, they offer the following

Recommended offer for individuals.
Dns management, Zone, Mx, Contacts, Status
2 email addresses (2GB quota/mailbox and 10MB attachment)
Whois Anonymous ( Details )

My question is the following : is their offer above is an extra option to the reserved domain name and shall I be able further to associate the new domaim name to my personal computer

any extra link will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To associate a domain with your PC (or any computer) you need either a static IP

or

A dynamic IP with a DNS is a service that automatically and periodically updates your DNS's A (IPv4) or AAAA (IPv6) records when your IP address changes. These are called DDNS services, but they tend to be clunky and not good for stable hosting.

This is the IP address that "IS" your computer access point on the internet and is provided by your internet service provider (ISP).

From there you need:

1. Domain registration
2. DNS hosting (usually free with domain registration, but you can pay for more stable services)

The others are things you don't really need but may want.

**MX:** This is part of DNS hosting its the "email" part of DNS
**Contacts:** No idea, sounds made up
**Mailbox:** if you want to store email, but you can do it on your local computer
**Whois anon:** means people cant see who has registered the domain (you)

Answer (score 0):

At your home internet, you need an IP that stays the same. So you need to ask your ISP if they can allocate a public IP to your account.

If you want to handle incoming requests and serve a website on your computer, you will have to setup a web server with software like apache or nginx. It might be best to have something like a Mikrotik firewall to handle incoming requests and to port forward incoming requests to your local ip addresses.

Honestly, why would you want this, it seems rather dangerous and you would have to have proper firewalls setup.

Also, to further answer your question, it seems like the option you are looking at offers DNS management as well, so all you will have to do is create a new A record with a name of "yourdomain.com" and a value containing your Public IP that your ISP assigned to you.